# What is the difference between "Height" and "Summit"؟

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the difference between "Height" and "Summit"?

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps it would be better if you split this question into two questions.

Comment: Removed the second question as it was unrelated to the main question.  (I will leave it to others to decide whether this is general reference or not.)

Comment: Downvoted as no research is shown, and voted to close as general reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height is a measurement of vertical extent. My height is under 2 meters.
A summit is the top of a mountain or hill. It is often used figuratively to mean best.

Outside is used for the complement of any space with a boundary. 
Outskirts is mainly used for edges of towns.

Did you have any specific questions that are not answered by the definitions in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

"Summit" is a location.  "Height" is a property.  But, since this is English, there's lots of variations!  "Summit" can also be a verb: "Edmund Hillary and Tenzing Norgay summited Everest on 29 May 1953", and "The Brooklyn Bridge connects Brooklyn Heights to downtown Manhattan".

"Outside" is a comparator (vs. "inside" e.g. "Go outside, you've watched too much TV already."), and "outskirts" is an area adjacent to, but on or just past the edge of a location ("Ikea and the other big block stores are on the outskirts of town").

Answer (score 1):

I want to disagree with both answers. In addition to a measurement, *the height* also be a locations. Both words can also be metaphorical. In my *American Heritage* dictionary, we have for the third definition of "height"

> 3: The highest or uppermost point.

*Oxford Learner's Dictionary* gives "the height of his career" as an example of this usage.

For "summit" we have

> 1: The highest point.

This can also be metaphorical, *Cambridge Learner's Dictionary* gives "the summit of his career" as an example.
So, in this sense, the words are synonyms.

When used for a physical high location the phrase is usually "the heights" or "a height", and it does not necessarily mean the uppermost point, but a high point or points, whereas "the summit" means the uppermost point.